# isql not working with complex row type

Tags: sql, informix

I have created a table in Informix:

```
create table tab_unmrow
(
   area integer,
   rectangle row(
            x integer,
            y integer,
            length integer,
            width integer)
);
```

Now when I do `select first 1 * from tab_unmrow` using `dbaccess`, this works fine.
But when using `isql`, I am getting this error:

> ```
> 1820: Host variable type has been changed between fetches or puts.
> Error in line 1
> ```

Can someone please suggest how can I fix this and why is this problem taking place.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nothing you can do about it directly, except report the bug to IBM.

Ultimately, there is a bug in ESQL/C, CQ idsdb00247065, which gives the error -1820.
You cannot reuse an SQL descriptor for LVARCHAR variables upon reopening the cursor unless the size for the LVARCHAR variables is set to the original size.  It's irritating because it is ESQL/C itself that has gone changing the sizes.

There's a workaround which applications can use, namely to store the original size for each LVARCHAR and reinstate that size in the SQL descriptor before the first FETCH (actually, after the OPEN).  But that would require the source to ISQL.  This issue is related to LVARCHAR even though it is not mentioned directly in the SQL you show because the way that client programs such as Informix SQL (`isql`) and DB-Access (`dbaccess`) handle complex types (such as a ROW type) is to convert the value to an LVARCHAR.

The fix will require (a) a fixed version of Informix ClientSDK (CSDK) and (b) a version of ISQL built with the fixed CSDK.

In the short term, you'll have to use DB-Access instead of ISQL to process SQL scripts, since you say DB-Access handles it OK.  Although DB-Access was carved out of ISQL 20 years ago, they've developed independently since then.

If there's a flaw in this diagnosis, it is that it applies to SQL descriptors, rather than `sqlda` structures (and you don't need to understand the details; there are simply two mechanisms for handling dynamic SQL, and the bug report applies strictly to one, but may be adaptable to the other as it is likely that `isql` uses `sqlda` rather than SQL descriptors). However, there's a very good chance that the two issues are intimately related even if it is not quite spot on.